# Don't know how to check input arguments in C

Tags: c

I'd like to check that the second input argument to my C program is either -f or -p. I'm using if statements to check this, and for some reason it doesn't recognize the argument as the string, yet when I print the argument it looks identical. I've tried it two ways, the first by copying the argument to a character array, and the second by checking the argument directly. What am I missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char flag[3] = "";
    memcpy(flag, argv[1],3);
    printf("%s\n", flag);

    // check that the second argument is either -f or -p
    if (flag == "-f")
    {
        printf("1");
    }
    else if (argv[1] == "-p")
    {
        printf("2");
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Second argument %s must be <-f> or <-p>\n", argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `strcmp` to compare strings.

Comment: Before you use `strcmp`, you must make sure that the string arguments are properly null-terminated, though. Otherwise `strcmp` will cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Therefore, you may want to consider using `strncpy_s` instead of `memcpy`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Do you think that argv[1] will ever be larger than the maximum buffer size for arguments? I don't think that there is no guard in compiler/system bootstrap for main. What I mean is that, that the sane behaviour for compiler will be to trim and zero terminate command line arguments.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel And thx for edit, I had a blush for improper education.

Comment: @yvw: You can rely on `argv[1]` being properly null-terminated. However, you cannot rely on `flag` being properly null-terminated, because the OP is using `memcpy` instead of `strncpy_s`. But your suggestion of using the function `strncmp` instead of `strcmp` is probably the simplest solution to the problem.

Comment: Before accessing `argv[1]`, you should make sure that `argc >= 2`. Otherwise, `argv[1] == NULL` and your program will crash.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel `flag` will be null terminated because `memcpy` carries that null into. Good point with cheking for argc. The `C` programmer should always do it.

Comment: @yvw: `flag` will only be null-terminated if `strlen(argv[1]) <= 2`. If `argv[1]` is larger, then `memcpy` will not copy the null terminator. Only `strncpy_s` is guaranteed to provide a null-terminated string in this situation.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel You have a point here. It is too late / too early in the morning for me to have a fresh eye. But I must say that OP know that the argv will be 2 chars in width. No need to use heavy artillery here.

Comment: @yvw: Your statements seem contradictory to me. On the one hand, you agree with me that the programmer should verify user input by checking `argc` before accessing `argv[1]`. However, you disagree with me that the programmer should verify user input by checking the length of `argv[1]`. In my opinion, a program should never crash when the user provides invalid input.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yes they are, but a little, not so much ;P What I meant to say, and maybe did it in a obscure way, is that, that no need to overcomplicate the simple. The OP does not need to use extra checks if he **knows** what the input will be. That is **a good rule** I think. On the other hand, your points are all correct. The OP should learn something from your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C is not `C++` or `Python`. The `==` operator does not work for comparing strings. What is does, is not what you intend it to do. It compares two pointers instead.

You shall use `strcmp` family of functions for that.

```
if(strcmp(flag, "-f") == 0){
 /* equals */
}
if(strncmp(flag, "-f", 2) == 0){
 /* equals */
}
```